# Getting notification from azure "Azure SQL DB database is an instance with high locking waits"

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, entity-framework-core, azure-sql-database

We have live tracking & delivering application.On each minute we are storing almost 50K spatial data and Update 100K spatial records but right now its working for few delivery boys once we increase the delivery boy count to 15+ our SQL databse server DTU usage get fulled(Used 50 DTUs & database is in elastic pool). and hence we are getting perofrmance issue.As I am new to azure I click on support request for azure database in azurefrom Menus and what it mentins the following issue with database
"Azure SQL DB database  is an instance with high locking waits"
any help or suggestion please

Tried with code optimization in .net core & spatial indexing & code optimization is also done.I also found from application insight that my Spatial query for fetching nearest delivery point of tracking delivery boy is taking much time but itb works fine when 15 or less users are running simaltaneously.Please see below linq code with Entity framework core & NetTopology for spatial data
`var deliveriesQuery = (from a in db.AddressPointDelivery.Where(w=>w.IsDelivered==false
                                                        && activeRouteJobIDList.Contains(w.RouteJobId.Value))
                                           from b in db.BreadCrumb.Where(w=>breadcrumbIDList.Any(bread=> bread == w.Id))
                                           //join rj in db.RouteJob on a.RouteJobId equals rj.Id
                                           where
                                               //activeRouteJobIDList.Contains(a.RouteJobId.Value)
                                               //&& breadcrumbIDList.Contains(b.Id)  &&
                                               Convert.ToDouble(a.Point.Distance(b.Point)) < 200
                                               //&& a.IsDelivered == false
                                              // && b.IsProcessed==false
                                           select new
                                           {
                                               breadcrumbId = b.Id,
                                               AddressPointId = a.Id,
                                               ///jobID = rj.JobId,
                                               routeJobId = a.RouteJobId,
                                               isUndelivered = !a.IsDelivered,
                                               CreatedOn=b.CapturedAt
                                           });
[Attached image is error message which I saw on click of support request][1]`

Comment: Is READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT enabled? `select name, is_read_committed_snapshot_on
from sys.databases`

Comment: yes its enabled..Can you please tell me impact of this?and what I needs to do

Comment: Do you have the Query Store enabled?

Comment: READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT is the default isolation level. What the Query Store tells you? http://www.sqlcoffee.com/Azure_0010.htm

Comment: It tells that READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT value for my db is true..So I think it means its enabled.I used following query to check select name, is_read_committed_snapshot_on from sys.databases

Comment: When you have performance problems in the database, it usually helps to look at the query store and see which queries are taking the most resources.  You may have to add an index or similar to get decent performance.  It could also be that the work you want to do requires a larger database reservation size if it is already optimally tuned.  Please review: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/monitoring-performance-by-using-the-query-store?view=sql-server-2017